# Issue with displaying an alert like view

Tags: ios, swift

In Android, on the click of a button I get a screen coming up (the one on the left with just the First Name and Last Name) and on click of the more button the other fields are also displayed (the image on the right).

I tried to achieve this by loading another view on the click of the button, but this shows a view completely filling the screen and not like the one in the image with limited height and the background view being greyed out.

Also to get a screen like the one on the left I  made their height constraints equal to 0, but though it showed just 2 textfields, the screen filled the whole screen and not like the one on the left.

Any idea as to how this can be achieved?

[image]   [image]

Comment: you can do it with constaint management of that view. Or you can check other libraries provided in cococontrols.com

Comment: managing the constraints still showed all components on the entire screen and not a short one like in the image with a faded background...

Comment: it's very easy man with constraint, you have to just take outlet of top constraint and decrease that constraint with desired height when clicked on more button.

Comment: you are right @JitendraModi...that's just what I did...But what I'm saying is  when I have just the firstname and lastname fields I want to display these 2 fields only in a short portion like one on the left with a faded background. And not just display the 2 fields on a full screen like it's happening now..

Answer (score 0):

To show **custom transition** while presenting a controller i.e.

**your first requirement** - a view completely filling the screen & not like the one in the image with limited height and the background view being greyed out.

you can use `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning`.

I have created a sample here:

https://github.com/pgpt10/Custom-Animator

Comment: Actually I don't want  a view completely filling the screen and want something like in the image...

Comment: With custom view controller transition, you can give whatever size you want to the controller.

Comment: You can use a UITableView for that and create multiple custom UITableViewCells according to your requirement.

Comment: So you are saying that I cannot use your library in that case...?